# What model of Hanwag boots are those?

Tags: boots, gear-identification

I bought a pair of Hanwag boots late in 2013 at Naturkompaniet in Norrköping, Sweden, and I've never loved a pair of boots more.  But now at least one of the shoes is in a bad state and a repair shop has adviced me it is not worth repairing.  I can't find any comparable boots in brick&mortar stores and I'm hesitant to buy online¹, unless I buy exactly what I have.  Unfortunately, *I don't know what I have*.  The labels are completely gone, I can just about identify them as Hanwag.

[image: Boot photo one]

[image: Boot photo two]

My boots are 26 cm high, have six layers of hooks on the edge and one in the middle.  The mass of each boot is nearly 1 kg (990 g).
They look a lot like the [Hanwag Brenner Wide GTX](http://www.hanwag.com/brenner-wide-gtxr), but I'm not sure.  Of course, it's not certain that the model I have is still sold.  Can anyone identify the exact model?

---

¹See [this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/16567/566).

---

P.S.: The reason Lancashire Shoe Repairs recommended they were not worth repairing:

[image: Damage]
Quote: *A total of £130 and because of the damage to the leather the boot will leak so in my opinion its just not worth repairing them*

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Maybe it was a [Trapper Top](https://hanwagboot.com/products/trapper-top-gtx)

Comment: yep, I'd agree that they're Trappers. Maybe the GTX: https://hanwagboot.com/collections/all-mens/products/xxx-trapper-gtx

Comment: @JonathanLandrum Oh, that one looks like an even better fit than the Trapper Top GTX, although only the colour appears to differ

Comment: i'm curious why your cobbler didn't want to work on your current pair? both trappers show they are fully resoleable. is it just the structure of the boot itself that is worn out? i have a pair of lacrosse boots that are 20 years old this year, and they still wear perfectly. they _do_ need new soles, but that's to be expected.

Comment: @JonathanLandrum See edit with another photo.

Comment: Ah. That's a shame. They seem like really nice boots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is still important, but those are the Standard Hanwag Trapper GTX, they are out of production, but some shops still have a few sizes in stock. I just ordered some here: https://www.recon-company.com/hanwag-trapper-gtx/3236
Hope that helps...